# problem of G action on set A.

Tags: group-theory

Let a group $G$ acts on a set $A$. Show that if $b=g.a$ for $a,b \in A$ and $g \in G$ then $G_b=g G_a g^{-1}$. find kernel of action if $G$ acts transitively on $A$.

Frankly, I have no idea how to answer this question. Need suggestions. Thanks

Comment: What are you stuck on: Do you know the definition of a group action? Do you know the definition of the set $G_a$? You need to give more information about what you need help on in order to get help.

Comment: i know definition of group action. but not$ G_a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$G_a=\{g\in G,\,g\cdot a=a\}$$

Now let $k\in gG_ag^{-1}$. This means $k=ghg^{-1}$ for some $h\in G_a$. We have $k\cdot b=ghg^{-1}\cdot b$. But $g\cdot a=b$ means $a=g^{-1}\cdot b$ and so $k\cdot b=gh\cdot a=g\cdot a=b$ and $k\in G_b$ which means $gGg^{-1}\subset G_b$.

Reciprocally if $k\in G_b$ we have $k\cdot b=b=g\cdot a$. This means $g^{-1}k\cdot(g\cdot a)=a$ so $g^{-1}kg\in G_a$ and therefore $k\in gG_ag^{-1}$.

Comment: thanks . what about second part? how to find kernel

Comment: Is the group finite? We need more context.

Comment: nothing given. i think one needs to assume.